# Как удалить View при завершении анимации

Tags: java, android, activity, анимация

Мне нужно удалить лишние TextView, анимация которых завершилась. Как это сделать?

Вот код `Activity`:

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout linLay[] = new LinearLayout[4];
eHandler hand = new eHandler();
final TextView ntv[][] = new TextView[4][75];
boolean isAnimStart;
Timer timer = new Timer();
static final String Tag = "MYTAG";
Button b[] = new Button[4];
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparam1;
RelativeLayout rlay;
Random rand = new Random();
int irand;
long time;
int result;
boolean isStart = false;
Animation[][] anim = new Animation[4][75];
TextView tvResult;
int xxx[]=new int[4];
boolean resume;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lparam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int aab = 0; aab < 4; aab++) {
        for (int aaa = 0; aaa < 75; aaa++) {
            anim[aab][aaa] = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    rlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.real);
    linLay[0] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay1);
    linLay[1] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay2);
    linLay[2] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLay3);
    linLay[3] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linlay4);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    b[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);


    gamer();
    timer.schedule(task, 300, 1);
}





TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // if (isStart) {
        gamer();
        //  }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    resume=true;
    if (resume) {

    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    resume=false;
}

public void gamer() {
    if (resume)
    time++;
    try {

            if (time >= 400) {


                irand = rand.nextInt(4);
                xxx[irand]++;
                if (xxx[irand]>74){
                    xxx[irand]=0;
                }
                ntv[irand][xxx[irand]]= new TextView(this);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ntv[irand][xxx[irand]].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        linLay[irand].addView(ntv[irand][xxx[irand]], lparam1);
                        ntv[irand][xxx[irand]].startAnimation(anim[irand][xxx[irand]]);

                    }
                });





                time = 0;
                for (int getrand=0;getrand<4;getrand++) {
                    for (int acc = 0; acc < 74; acc++) {
                        if (ntv[getrand][acc] != null) {
                            final int finalAcc = acc;
                            final int finalGetrand = getrand;


                            try {
                                anim[getrand][acc].setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

                                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                        Log.d(Tag, "Анимация началась");
                                    }


                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                        Log.d(Tag, "Анимация завершилась");
                                        if (ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc]!=null) {
                                            if ( ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc].getParent()!=null)
                                            try {
                                                ((ViewGroup)ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc].getParent()).removeView(ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc]);

                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                               Log.d(Tag,"что-то произошло",e);
                                            }
                                            ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc] = null;
                                        }

                                    }


                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d(Tag,"Ошибка",e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(Tag, "ошитбка", e);
    }
    boolean isButton[] = new boolean[4];
    for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
        b[a].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.b1) {
                    result++;
                } else {

                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.b2) {
                    result++;
                } else {

                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.b3) {
                    result++;
                } else {

                }
                if (v.getId() == R.id.b4) {
                    result++;
                } else {

                }
                tvResult.setText("Результаь = "+result);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class eHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //if (!isStart) {
        // if (v.getId() == R.id.b1 || v.getId() == R.id.b2 || v.getId() == R.id.b3 || v.getId() == R.id.b4) {
        //    isStart = true;
        // }
        // }


    }
}
```

}

При выполнение данного кода вылетает ошибка:

```
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2488)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10420)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2597)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10385)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:849)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-06 18:45:36.252 6465-6465/com.gopea_system.runner E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Много кода. Укажите строку в которой у вас вылетай NullPointerException.

Comment: А вы бы не могли указать строку, в которой происходит ошибка, а то так труднее понять, но подозреваю, что вы пытались использовать какой-то объект, который равен null

Comment: Проблема в том, что почему-то Android studio не указывает строку , где происходит ошибка. Ошибка не вылетает когда я убираю строку ((ViewGroop)ntv[]finallGetrand[finallAcc]).etPatent()).removeView(ntv[finallGetrand][finallAcc]);

Answer (score 1):

все достаточно просто, вешаете listener на завершение анимации, а после завершения анимации

```
((ViewGroup) textView.getParent()).removeView(textView);
```

вызываете для каждого ненужного textView.

---

### UPD

судя по вашим комментариям вы скорее всего обращаетесь к пустому Parent. Разбейте на 2 строки получение Parent и удаление из него View, тогда будет видно. Может вы просто несколько раз вызываете это для одного и того же View.

Comment: Как бы автор так и делает, просто некорректно задал вопрос. Проблема в том, что у него null выскакивает и судя по всем удаление происходит успешно, поэтому проблема возникает после

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, я потом увидел, но вопрос был поставлен так, я и дал на него ответ. Так как таким образом с фабом боролся сегодня, из-за behavior не мог его скрыть.) А в комментарии, я написал ,что автор должен указать строку.

Comment: Да не, я сам считаю, что автор некорректно вопрос поставил

Comment: Я попытался сделать так, ка вы посоветовали
`final int finalAcc = acc;  final int finalGetrand = getrand;
final ViewGroup a = ((ViewGroup) ntv[getrand][acc].getParent());`
дальше идет удаление
`a.removeView(ntv[finalGetrand][finalAcc]);`
И ,все равно, вылетает ошибка, но если убрать строчку удаления ошибки нет.
P.S. Остальной код не изменен.